# Prove that $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\times \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\subseteq \mathcal B (\mathbb R^2)$

Tags: measure-theory

I need to prove that

$$\mathcal A(\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\times \mathcal B(\mathbb R))= \mathcal B (\mathbb R^2)$$

Where $\mathcal B$ is the generated Borel algebra and $\mathcal A$ is the generated $\sigma$-algebra. I've reduced this to the problem of showing that $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\times \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\subseteq \mathcal B (\mathbb R^2)$. However, I really don't know where to start on this.

There must be a solution not involving things like the Borel rank, by the way, since we didn't cover that in class.

Comment: What's your definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra? The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets?

Comment: @saz Yes.${{}}$

Comment: check if the product of two $\sigma$ -algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra. I don't know if it's true. It seems to me that it's true. If yes then it's easy with the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $$\mathcal{D} := \{A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}); \forall O \subseteq \mathbb{R} \, \text{open}: A \times O \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\}$$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and conclude that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. ($\mathcal{O}$ denote the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.)
2. Prove in a similar way that $\mathcal{O} \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
3. Conclude from $$A \times B = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} (A \times B(0,n)) \cap (B(0,n) \times B)$$ that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your notation. What is $\mathcal D$? And what does $B(0, n)$ mean?

Comment: @JackM $\mathcal{D}$ is defined in step 1. $B(0,n)$ is the open ball centered at $0$ of radius $n$, i.e. $B(0,n) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}; |x|<n\}$.

Comment: What I mean is I don't understand the definition of $\mathcal D$. The semicolon and colon aren't how I usually write set definitions. Is it $\{A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R) \mid (\forall O\in\mathcal O)\ A \times O \in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)\}$ ?

Comment: @JackM $\mathcal{D}$ is the set of all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for any open set $O \in \mathcal{O}$, we have $A \times O \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.