# Show $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \otimes \mathscr B(\mathbb R) = \mathscr B(\mathbb R^2)$

Tags: measure-theory

How do I show $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \otimes \mathscr B(\mathbb R) = \mathscr B(\mathbb R^2)$ where $\mathscr B$ is Borel Algebra.

I don't quite sure how to prove this relation, do I show that they have the same generating set? or find  $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \otimes \mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ and $  \mathscr B(\mathbb R^2)$ explicitly and show that they are equal?

Comment: See e.g. this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/979714/)

Comment: @saz Is $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \times \mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ same is $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \otimes \mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: Yes, this follows from the very definition of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.